# AS3 hitTestPoint always returns false for one function

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a movieclip I drawn, called Map. It has a child with the name Wall. I'm trying to make a function that returns a 2d tile array of if there is something in that tile or not, for pathfinding.

The problem is, levelGrid is entirely false. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have filled the whole movieclip (Wall) with bright red, and yes it still returns false.

The x and y of both Map and Wall is 0, so I don't think there should be issues with hitTestPoint accepting global x / y.

They are added to a display list.

My other movement hittest works fine.

My code:

```
public function levelMap() {
    for (var i = 0; i < height / 25; i++) {
        levelGrid[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < width / 25; j++) {
            levelGrid[i][j] = this.getChildByName("Wall").hitTestPoint(j*25,i*25,true);
        }
    }
    trace(levelGrid);
}
```

Thanks in advance (levelGrid is a class variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a visual test out of your code. I did not change any functionality though so I think your problem is your graphics. Check the width, height och positions of the graphics. If you dont get anything in the Array, then maybe those values are not set correctly.

Each dot represent a hitTestPoint in this test. If its green you have a hit (true return value). Red means no hit. Hope this helps.

---

TestHitPoint.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class TestHitPoint extends Sprite
    {

        private static const TILE_SIZE : int = 25;

        private var levelGrid : Array;

        public function TestHitPoint()
        {

            // add graphics to test
            addChild( new WallGraphics() );

            // fix array
            levelGrid = new Array();

            // loop
            for (var i : int = 0; i < height / TILE_SIZE; i++)
            {
                levelGrid[i] = [];

                for (var j : int = 0; j < width / TILE_SIZE; j++)
                {
                    var success : Boolean = this.getChildByName("Wall").hitTestPoint(j*TILE_SIZE, i*TILE_SIZE, true);

                    levelGrid[i][j] = success;

                    addChild( new PositionMarker(j*TILE_SIZE, i*TILE_SIZE, success) );
                }
            }
        }

        public function levelMap() : void
        {

        }

    }
}
import flash.display.Sprite;

internal class WallGraphics extends Sprite
{
    public function WallGraphics() 
    {
        name = "Wall";

        with(graphics)
        {
            beginFill(0x0000FF, 1);
            drawRect(100, 50, 60, 200);
            drawRect(50, 100, 200, 50);
            endFill();
        }
    }
}

internal class PositionMarker extends Sprite
{
    public function PositionMarker(posX : Number, posY : Number, success : Boolean) 
    {
        with(graphics)
        {
            beginFill((success) ? 0x00FF00 : 0xFF0000, 1);
            drawCircle(posX, posY, 4);
            endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: Sadly I can't get it to work on my main project. A new project works fine. :/ (yes, I copy and pasted the exact same code)

Comment: Ok, if I do it in my document class it works. Weird. Local/global positions? But every parent of it has a x and y of 0, 0 (when the code is executed)

Comment: I am just going to believe it is a ghost who is ruining my day. Time to put all my wall code in my document class. Thanks!

Comment: I think I found it. The document class addChilds the game object *after* the constructor is executed. And guess when I executed the function? Yes, before the parent of the parent is added to child. Learned a lesson about using the added to child event listener today.